# How do I use a standard active record for some models when i am using the datafabric gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sharding

I am using the data-fabric gem, sharding between 2 machines.

However, I would like to use the standard activerecord functions for some tables.

Anyone has a similar experience achieving this?